# Search by Extension ID OR UUID in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have a webpage that some Extension injects some script(in Firefox) in the DOM, I was able to find the UUID of the extension but I can't find the extension ID
What I'm looking for is get the extension ID (using js) to search for it.

Comment: It's in `about:debugging`

Comment: I know that already but how can access that from a js script in the DOM ?

Comment: There's no way.